# How to query findOne() in mongoose such that we get subset of array of documents which satisfy particular condition?

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

When I query this

`const pendingOfThisShop = await ShopProfile.findOne({ shop: req.shop.id, "shopsAffiliate.status":"pending" },{ shopsAffiliate: 1, _id: 0 }`

I get an object like this

```
{
"shopsAffiliate": [
    {
        "status": "approved",
        "_id": "5db315a6de255a4444b0987b",
        "affiliateId": "5db31263a362ed4ed84c7ad5"
    },
    {
        "status": "pending",
        "_id": "5db315c5de255a4444b0987d",
        "affiliateId": "5db2b4713db4101e48836f0a"
    }
]}
```

I get both status:"approved" and status:"pending". I only want to get those objects in shopsAffiliate array which have status of "pending". What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get both status:"approved" and status:"pending"

your query is returning the expected result.

`shopsAffiliate` is an array of nested documents. `shopsAffiliate` itself is part of documents inside `ShopProfile` collection. Your query checks for any document in `ShopProfile` that meets following 2 conditions

1. `shop: req.shop.id`
2. `"shopsAffiliate.status":"pending"`

When it finds any document that matches both above mentioned conditions, it returns the **whole document**. It doesn't cares whether there are other documents in `shopsAffiliate` array of the matching document that do not have `pending` status, it just needs to **find atleast 1 document inside `shopsAffiliate` array that has `pending` status**, as soon as it finds one, it returns the **whole document**.

> I only want to get those objects in shopsAffiliate array which have
>   status of "pending". What should I do?

you can use [aggregation operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to get desired result

```
const pendingOfThisShop = await ShopProfile.aggregate([
      {
          $match: {
              shop: req.shop.id,
              "shopsAffiliate.status": "pending"
          }
      },
      {
          $unwind: "$shopsAffiliate"
      },
      {
          $match: { "shopsAffiliate.status": "pending" }
      }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks I am using mongoose so to convert req.shop.id to ObjectId I just replace req.shop.id with this mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.shop.id). And it worked. This is the exact code that worked `const pendingOfThisShop = await ShopProfile.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          shop: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.shop.id),
          "shopsAffiliate.status": "pending"
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$shopsAffiliate"
      },
      {
        $match: { "shopsAffiliate.status": "pending" }
      },
      {
        $project: { shopsAffiliate: 1 }
      }
    ]);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const pendingOfThisShop = await ShopProfile.findOne({ shop: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.shop.id), "shopsAffiliate.status":"pending" },{ "shopsAffiliate": {'$elemMatch': {"status":"pending"}}, _id: 0 });
```

Comment: I tried this and It says that -> Can't use $elemMatch with String.